# what does status=2147746065 mean? firefox error

Tags: firefox

I am trying to pull a font file using @font-face but firefox does not pick up the font and it gives this error status=2147746065. it doesn't really tell me what is wrong. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: http://james-ross.co.uk/mozilla/misc/nserror?2147746065 says this is a pretty generic error code.

Not much else to say here without an idea of what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm fairly certain it just means that the font could not be obtained.

I recently fixed this issue by ensuring the font was on the server (Visual studio had an incorrect build type on the font; it should have been 'Content'.

I also needed to set up a mime type in IIS as

application/x-font-woff .woff

or put it in your web.config as

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Also note that this mimeType is not recognised as a standard at present.

Comment: I used the web.config method, and it's job done. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try disabling the extension (for example WIFI finder or another), then restart. The problem with error 2147746065 disappears.