# Some fonts not downloading in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

Having an issue downloading some fonts in Firefox only.:

This font works fine:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family:"Inconsolata";
    src:url("/fonts/Inconsolata.ttf");
}
```

This does not:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family:"MyriadPro-LightCond";
    src:url("/fonts/MyriadProLightCond.otf");
}
```

adding the format doesn't help either:

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family:"MyriadPro-LightCond";
    src:url("/fonts/MyriadProLightCond.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

I have tried setting the origin policy to fix the localhost issue (I even published it to a server):

```
security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy;false
```

Here is the console log:

```
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "MyriadPro-LightCond" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0): status=2147746065
source: http://localhost/app/fonts/MyriadProLightCond.otf
```

Again, this only happens for some fonts. The other browsers do no complain.

Comment: Try using the Web Open Font Format (WOFF) instead. You might be able to use fontsquirrel: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Thanks Dylan, it's a great idea, but I don't believe this will be an option for me due to licensing.

Comment: Not enough data, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509012/what-does-status-2147746065-mean-firefox-error

Comment: Try using Droid Sans as it's a close match to Myriad Pro. http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans

Comment: Jukka - Don't believe it's an IIS issue since it serves the file to other browsers.

Comment: Dylan - I will suggest this font. It's not my call, but I do believe we may need to try another font. Hopefully this works in IE8 =/. I haven't add browser issues like this since 2006!